# UV orientation affects shading

Tags: uv, normals, lighting

I would like to **follow up** on a previous question about **UVs affecting shading** in a weird way.

I am in the process of **exporting a scene to Unreal Engine 4** and stumble upon this issue as I baked the lighting :

[image]

I was thinking it was coming from Unreal since I wasn't the only one facing this issue. So **I created [this thread](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/935275/view.html) on UE4 Q&A forum**.

I checked and double-checked everything until I realize that **the orientation of the UV's were creating this issue**.

[image]

So after **I "R180"ed my UV island the shading got fixed**.

**My question is why ?** 
I should be able to orient my UV islands as I see fit without affecting shading, right ?

Is there something I forgot to check in the FBX export ? Is this related to the way Blender handles shading ?

Any idea is welcome :)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you use normal map it's normal.

Comment: So eventually, I found what the issue was. The texture sampler I use in Ureal was type "color" instead of "normal". Causing those weird shading errors. Still when I use a normal map inside Blender I can see the same shading effect, I might be doing something wrong in my material in my blender scene as well...